# How to associat a model to itself in a Many to Many way using Sails.js/Waterline?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a sails.js project and I need a Model to be connected to itself as many to many, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes(ish)

You can create a second model (for the purpose of the association). The second model would reference the same table as the first model and then you just create an association the way you normally would.